# Displaying multiple linklabels in a form

Tags: c#

I have a C# Windows form which based on user input will fetch multiple download links. Now I am facing difficulties in displaying this links to user so that they can click on their desired link to download the files.

I can display everything using `MessageBox` but could not make links in `MessageBox` and as the download link is quite long it is not user friendly.

I tried LinkLabel following example from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288420(v=vs.71).aspx. This can work but only for 1 link.

Any idea how I can do this for multiple links or is there any other method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own form to display message to user. Also, use TableLayoutPanel and LinkLabel to display multiple links in the created custom message form like below.

```
string[] links = new string[10];
TableLayoutPanel panel = new TableLayoutPanel();
panel.RowCount = links.Length;
panel.ColumnCount = 1;
int currentRow = 0;
foreach (var link in links)
{
    LinkLabel linkLabel = new LinkLabel();
    linkLabel.Text = "Click here to get more info.";
    linkLabel.Links.Add(6, 4, link);
    linkLabel.OnLinkClicked += OnLinkClicked;
    panel.Controls.Add(linkLabel, 0, currentRow++);
}
this.Controls.Add(panel);
```

The event handler looks like below,

```
void OnLinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(e.Link);
}
```

Comment: But when I click on the link, nothing happens. How do I trigger the link to open in a browser or start the file download?

Comment: LinkLabel has event OnLinkClicked event. you have to register this event for all link label. In the event handler you can just call,
Process.Start(eargs.Link).

Comment: Refer this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.link.aspx for display multiple links in one LinkLabel with out TableLayoutPanel and open the link in brower while user clicks on it. (Check the example in this link) :-)

Answer (score 2):

Refer the example code in this msdn link. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.link.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Process.Start(e.Link.LinkData.ToString());
```